# Vaadin tabs with custom content

Tags: javascript, web, components, vaadin

I have a Vaadin tab component with custom content. In some tabs are buttons insted of simple text. When I navigate the tab component with the keyboard, I can navigate the tabs with the arrow keys.

When I want to activate the button inside a tab, I need to press the tab key again to set the tabindex from the tab to the button.

How can I activate the button with the keyboard navigation without pushing the tab key twice?

In the vaadin tab demo, there is an [example of a tab with custom content](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-tabs/java-examples). Instead of a button, there is a checkbox in a tab but the probleme is the same.

Comment: You referenced a Java example, but your tags suggest JavaScript usage.  This is not by accident and you really want for JS, right?

Comment: Yes, the example of the tab with custom content is only in the Java example. You can switch to the HTML (web components) examples by clicking the HTML button in the left navigation.

Comment: My first idea was, to set the tabindex of the active tab to -1 if the tab has a button as a child. But I don`t know if this will work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. Now I can activate the button inside a tab with my keyboard.

I found the answer to my question in the standard [vaadin-tab web component](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-tabs/blob/v3.0.0/src/vaadin-tab.html)

In the `_onKeyup` function they did exactly the same with an anchor  element inside a tab.

In my web component, I've added the `_onKeyup` function and modified the selector to use a vaadin-button instead of an anchor  element:

```
_onKeyup(event) {
          const willClick = this.hasAttribute('active');

          super._onKeyup(event);

          if (willClick) {
            const slottedButton = this.querySelector('vaadin-button');
            if (slottedButton) {
              slottedButton.click();
            }
          }
        }
```